# Angular Modal Popup Form Validation Not Working

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

**Scenario:**

I am new to angular. When I click the button **Enable Access**, I'm trying to create a Modal Popup Form in Angular. The issue I am facing is it is not checking the validations like **Required**. It is submitted without checking. How to fix this issue.

**Component.html**

```
<button style="margin-left: 70%" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="open(content)">EnableAccess</button>
<ng-template #content let-modal>
<div class="modal-header">
    <h2 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title"> Submit Request </h2>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form [formGroup]="validatingForm" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="req_full_name"> Requester's Full Name </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="req_full_name" name="req_full_name" [(ngModel)]="requesterFullName" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required />
            </div>
            <!-- <small *ngIf="validatingForm.get(arn)" class="text-danger"> ARN is required </small> -->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="req_email"> Requester's Email </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="req_email" name="req_email" [(ngModel)]="requesterEmail" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
            </div>
            <!-- <small *ngIf="validatingForm.get(arn)" class="text-danger"> ARN is required </small> -->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="arn"> ARN </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="arn" name="arn" [(ngModel)]="arn" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
            </div>
            <!-- <small *ngIf="validatingForm.get(arn)" class="text-danger"> ARN is required </small> -->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="manager_email"> Manager Email </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="manager_email" name="manager_email" [(ngModel)]="managerEmail" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
            </div>
            <!-- <small *ngIf="validatingForm.get(arn)" class="text-danger"> ARN is required </small> -->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="bucket_name"> Bucket Name </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="bucket_name" disabled name="bucket_name" [(ngModel)]="bucketName" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
            </div>
            <!-- <small *ngIf="validatingForm.get(arn)" class="text-danger"> ARN is required </small> -->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="bucket_prefix"> Bucket Prefix </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="bucket_prefix" name="bucket_prefix" [(ngModel)]="bucketPrefix" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
            </div>
            <!-- <small *ngIf="validatingForm.get(arn)" class="text-danger"> ARN is required </small> -->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="reason"> Reason </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="reason" name="reason" [(ngModel)]="reason" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
            </div>
            <!-- <small *ngIf="validatingForm.get(arn)" class="text-danger"> ARN is required </small> -->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="req_lev_access"> Requester Level Access </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="req_lev_access" name="req_lev_access" [(ngModel)]="requestLevelAccess" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
            </div>
            <!-- <small *ngIf="validatingForm.get(arn)" class="text-danger"> ARN is required </small> -->
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="modal.close('Save click')"> Submit </button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="modal.dismiss('dismiss')"> Cancel </button>
</div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
import {FormControl, Validators, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    validatingForm: FormGroup;
    constructor() {
    this.validatingForm = new FormGroup({
      dbname: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      tablename: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      tablelocation: new FormControl('', Validators.required),

      **// Tried these both methods to do the required validation**

      requester_full_name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      requester_email: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      manager_email: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      bucket_name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      bucket_prefix: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      reason: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      request_level_access: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      arn: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    });
   }
```

[Angular Modal Popup Form Validation Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Dngd.png)

Comment: can you please provide stackblitz url ?

Answer (score 0):

Tyr creating the form in the below way:

```
 this.validatingForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     dbname: ['', [Validators.required]],
     tablename: ['', [Validators.required]]
 });

<form [formGroup]="validatingForm" (ngsubmit)="submit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>DB Name<label>
        <input formControlName="dbname">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Table Name<label>
        <input formControlName="tablename">
        <ng-container *ngIf="validatingForm.get('tablename').hasError('required')">
            It is a Mandatory Field.
        </ng-container>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```